# Unable to read modis sst netcdf file in matlab

Tags: matlab, netcdf, modis

I'm using Matlab to read MODIS Aqua sea surface temperature data. Unfortunately I am not able to do it. It will be great if any of you can help me with that.

```
ncread('A2010091081000.L2_LAC_SST.x.nc','sst');
Error using internal.matlab.imagesci.nc/getGroupAndVarid (line 2083)
Could not find variable or group 'sst' in file.
Error in internal.matlab.imagesci.nc/read (line 593)
            [gid, varid] = getGroupAndVarid(this, location);
Error in ncread (line 58)
vardata = ncObj.read(varName, varargin{:})*;
```